# Python multiprocessing error when trying to run a process pool from within a spawned process

Tags: python, optimization, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a project where I star 4 processes to query different databases.

```
self.counter_puller.start() 
self.counter_puller.join()
```

This happens in the file where main is. Now within `Counter_puller` process I am calling `calculate_kpis` which is a method of class Calculator(object).

```
class CountersPuller(Process):
    _db = None 
    _logger = None 
    _sites_info = None

def __init__(self, config, output_dir, area, level):
    Process.__init__(self)
...
calculator.calculate_kpis(self._pulled_counters)`
```

And in that method I have the process pool:

```
with Pool(globals.NUM_KPI_WORKERS) as exe: 
   results = exe.starmap(worker_calcuiating_kpi, zip(self._kpis, counters))   
for res in results:        
    calculated_kpis[res.columns[0]] = res.values
```

When testing this part of the code `calculate_kpis()` from a unit test everything works fine but when I run the full program I get an error when initializing the process pool.

```
Process NrPmDataCountersPuller-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/var/www/html/kpi-analyzer/src/dbAggregator/counters_puller.py", line 135, in run
    calculator.calculate_kpis(self._pulled_counters)
  File "/var/www/html/kpi-analyzer/src/dbAggregator/kpi_calculator.py", line 268, in calculate_kpis
    self._generate_and_save_kpi_carrier_level(input_data)
  File "/var/www/html/kpi-analyzer/src/dbAggregator/kpi_calculator.py", line 280, in _generate_and_save_kpi_carrier_level
    calculated_kpis = self.__calculate_carrier_level(input_data)
  File "/var/www/html/kpi-analyzer/src/dbAggregator/kpi_calculator.py", line 349, in __calculate_carrier_level
    with Pool(globals.NUM_KPI_WORKERS) as exe:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 119, in Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 191, in __init__
    self._setup_queues()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 346, in _setup_queues
    self._inqueue = self._ctx.SimpleQueue()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 113, in SimpleQueue
    return SimpleQueue(ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 341, in __init__
    self._rlock = ctx.Lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/context.py", line 68, in Lock
    return Lock(ctx=self.get_context())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 162, in __init__
    SemLock.__init__(self, SEMAPHORE, 1, 1, ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 58, in __init__
    kind, value, maxvalue, self._make_name(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/synchronize.py", line 116, in _make_name
    return '%s-%s' % (process.current_process()._config['semprefix'],
TypeError: 'Config' object is not subscriptable
```

Any hint that could help me move forward would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a `_config` member in your `CountersPuller` class which is clashing with the `_config` member of python's `Process` class.

avoid assigning to or using the member name `_config` in this class, or avoid the whole inheritance thing and just pass your configurations as an argument to your function.

you can easily replicate the bug using the following code

```
import multiprocessing

class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._config = None

    def run(self):
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proc = MyProcess()
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
```

that's one more reason to favor composition over inheritance that goes into the list, and this is how you do it without inheritence.

```
import multiprocessing

class MyProcess:

    def __init__(self):
        self._config = "hello"

    def do_something(self):
        print(self._config)
        with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    proc_config = MyProcess()
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc_config.do_something)
    proc.start()
    proc.join()
```